# Define a list with type

Tags: python

I come from Java, and I want to do some [data transfer objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) (DTOs) like this:

```
class ErrorDefinition():
    code = ''
    message = ''
    exception = ''

class ResponseDTO():
    sucess = True
    errors = list() # How do I say it that it is directly of the ErrorDefinition() type, to not import it every time that I'm going to append an error definition?
```

Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> errors = list() # How do I say it that it is directly of the ErrorDefinition() type, to not import it every time that I'm going to append an error definition?

I am not sure what you are trying to say in this comment, but if I understand right, the best way to get something close is to define a method to add an error.

```
class ResponseDTO(object): # New style classes are just better, use them.

    def __init__(self):
        self.success = True # That's the idiomatic way to define an instance member.
        self.errors = [] # Empty list literal, equivalent to list() and more idiomatic.

    def append_error(self, code, message, exception):
        self.success = False
        self.errors.append(ErrorDefinition(code, message, exception))
```

Answer (score 66):

You can type a list as of Python 3.5

https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

```
from typing import List

vector: List[float] = list()
```

or

```
from typing import List

vector: List[float] = []
```

Python is dynamically typed however https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/

Typing makes it easier to read code, easier understand it, make efficient use of your IDE tooling and create higher quality software. I guess that's why it's in the PEP.

Comment: Found this and was confused for a fair while because my misunderstanding of it gave some particularly confusing error messages. Turns out, you can't define a list like 

"self.alist=List[float]"

if you want to define a list with a type, it has to be 

"self.alist: List[float] = []"

Comment: @Rugnir yup you're correct, I rushed my response. I've corrected the answer.

Comment: `from typing import List` is [deprecated](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.List) as of [3.9](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.9.html#type-hinting-generics-in-standard-collections).  You can use `list` with no import: `vector : list[float] = list()`.

Comment: ...or `vector = list[float]()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this now with [type hint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) by specifying the type from the `__init__` function. Just as a simple example:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, value: int):
        self.value = value


class Bar:
    def __init__(self, values: List[Foo]):
        self.values = values
```

With this, we know the `values` of `Bar` should hold a list of reference to `Foo`; and the `value` of `Foo` should be an integer. Let's see what we have when we use it by mistake:

```
foo = Foo(1)
print(foo.value.split()) 
#               ^^^^^ Hint warning: Unresolved attribute reference 'split' for class 'int'

bar = Bar([foo])
print(bar.values[0] + 2) 
#     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Hint warnings: Expected type 'int', got 'Foo' instead
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can't define a type for a list. You're going to need to import ErrorDefinition every time (which looks like the already existing `Exception` class).

Answer (score 0):

Please explain what you mean by "import it every time".

You need to reconsider using class-level attributes before you have explored exactly what they do, especially when you use mutable types like lists. Consider this:

```
>>> class Borg(object):
...     alist = list()
...
>>> a = Borg()
>>> b = Borg()
>>> a.alist.append('qwerty')
>>> a.alist
['qwerty']
>>> b.alist
['qwerty']
>>>
```

Not what you wanted? Use the usual Python idiom of setting up what you need in the class's `__init__` method:

```
>>> class Normal(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.alist = list()
...
>>> x = Normal()
>>> y = Normal()
>>> x.alist.append('frobozz')
>>> x.alist
['frobozz']
>>> y.alist
[]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Dominus said,
`from typing import List` is deprecated since Python 3.9.
You don't need to import something, you can use list.
Example:
`my_list: list[float] = list()`

Answer (score -6):

Python is dynamically typed, and you just don't declare types for variables like you do in Java. [The official tutorial](http://docs.python.org/) is highly suggested reading at this stage.

Comment: While this may be true, Type Hinting is something that makes life so much nicer and helps you avoid stupid mistakes. See: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/

Comment: Python has optional type checking. This is advice against both the spirit of the question as well as the intention and capabilities of the language.