# C# class to Python class

Tags: python, c#

I have an class defined in C# as Servicing and i need to convert this code to Python. So how do i convert the Servicing class to a list datatype in python and then use it in Adjusted class?

```
class Servicing
{
    public long StatementName{ get; set; }
    public string City{ get; set; }
}
```

Now this class is used in another class Adjusted

```
class Adjusted
{ 
    public List<Servicing> Services{ get; set; }
}
```

For Servicing class I can define the constructor like this and then have its setter and getter defined too.

```
class Servicing:
    def __init__(self):
        self._StatementName=0.0
        self._City= ""
```

But how do I use this Servicing class in a similar way how it is used in Adjusted class?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Define a list with type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924469/define-a-list-with-type)

Comment: Note that, unlike c#, python is a dynamically typed language and that  type hints are _hints_. They might make your IDE's auto-complete or linter behave differently, but to the interpreter it doesn't matter (unless you use something like mypy, in which case it does). In a regular interpreter, you could _hint_ a list as shown, but nothing would stop. you from adding a plain old integer (or any object) in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python doesn't need setters or getters since all class attributes and methods are public. Instead values are given as parameters to `__init__` and class is initialized that way. List are almost as easy, just add new values with `.append` or extend with another iterable with `.extend`

```
class Servicing:
    # Default values for class
    def __init__(self, StatementName=0.0, City=""):
        self.StatementName = StatementName
        self.City = City

class Adjusted:
    def __init__(self, Services=[]):
        self.Services = []
        self.Services.extend(Services)

    def add_service(self, StatementName=0.0, City=""):
        new_servicing = Servicing(StatementName, City)
        self.Services.append(new_servicing)

a_servicing = Servicing(1.2, "London")
print(Servicing.City)
a_servicing.City = "Boston"
print(Servicing.City)
```

When you get more familiar with python, there is a way to implement getter/setter with the [`@property` decorator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property).

Comment: Shouldn't an uninitialized list be 'None', not '[]' (empty list) ?

Comment: @DaveDoknjas In this case I preferred it to be an empty list, because then you can just append to it, without needing to do a None check first. There might be some downside to this depending on OPs application, but I didn't see any based on the question.

Comment: I was just looking at the C# equivalent where the field is null at that point, but I understand what you're saying.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Adjusted:

    def __init__(self):
        self.Services = None


class Servicing:

    def __init__(self):
        self.StatementName = 0
        self.City = None
```

Don't know much about Python, But it should be something like the above.

Please ignore compilation errors, As I am not from Pythn background.